# Neo4j: Count relationships' properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher, relationship

I have this kind of relationship `(:User)-[:COMMENTS]->(:Topic)` where `:COMMENTS` has two properties (`tweet` and `sentiment`).

I would like to count and group the several different sentiment included in the relationships, like this kind of output:

- angry: 25
- sad: 85
- love 155
- hilarious: 13

How can I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution found. The query needed is:

```
MATCH ()-[r:COMMENTS]->() 
return count(r), r.sentiment
```

Comment: `count(r)` should also suffice, can you please confirm?

Comment: yes, the test succeded. I'm gonna edit the answer. Thank you.